# Anmeldung when moving apartments

Tags: germany

Suppose I move from apartment to another, would I have to abmeldung my original anmeldung and then anmeldung again, or can I anmeldung directly in the second place?

Would the answer differ the apartment transition were between cities or states?

Comment: An Abmeldung (de-registration) is only required when leaving Germany. Moving inside Germany (including inside the same house) only requires an Anmeldung (registration).

Comment: Do I need to deregister my house when moving tho? @MarkJohnson

Comment: 'moving tho': what does that mean? Everything else is done automaticlly when registering your new residence in Germany.

Comment: tho is contraction of the word "though". But, alright, I guess that answers my question. It's all done automatically was the point I was seeking.

Comment: _Meldung_ is a noun (German _-ung_ is the same as English _-ing_).  The first paragraph is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] would I have to abmeldung my original anmeldung and then anmeldung again, or can I anmeldung directly in the second place?

§ 17 (2) [BMG](http://Bundesrecht.Juris.de/englisch_bmg/index.html) pretty clearly states:

> ¹Anyone abandoning their dwelling without occupying a new domestic place of abode, has to deregister with the registration office within two weeks after moving out.
> ²It is possible to deregister up to one week ahead; […]

As long as you move *between* apartments in Germany, you merely need to register.
The responsible clerk will ask you whether you are keeping the other apartment.
You say you have permanently left the other apartment and this information will be automatically forwarded to the former authorities for the purposes of implicit deregistration.
It is as simple as that.

Although it is possible to deregister at your old place, this deregistration does in no way replace the registration at your new place.
You still need to appear in person in your new community, kind of “verifying” that you *are* in fact moving in there and not just claiming to.
The procedure at the (new) registration office might take a minute less since the clerk will only need to tick a box:
“Yes, Tryst has arrived here and all logged details are correct.”
Obviously there is no real benefit in doing that.

> Would the answer differ the apartment transition were between cities or states?

No, the Federal Registration Act is a *federal* law.
§ 55 BMG authorizes states to enact laws regulating *certain* things, but this does in no way affect your obligation to register/deregister.

---

Bottom line:
If moving takes *longer than* two weeks, you will need to register the new apartment once you start moving in into it and unregister the old apartment  once you finished moving.
If moving lasts less than two weeks, you can do both registration/deregistration in one go.
The date of your move is when you switch sleeping places.
If you alternate sleeping between places, you officially maintain multiple residences.